# Getting generated value from Identity Column in EF Core 7

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, savechanges, identity-column

I still get zero as response on my Edentity Column after `SaveChangesAsync()`.

Here's my entity

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR"), StringLength(50)]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR"), StringLength(50), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string? Email { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string? Address { get; set; }
    }

    public static class PersonExtensionMethod
    {
        public static PersonResponse ToResponse(this Person person)
        {
            return new PersonResponse()
            {
                PersonID = person.PersonID,
                Name = person.Name,
                Email = person.Email,
                DateOfBirth = person.DateOfBirth,
                Address = person.Address,
            };
        }
    }
```

Here's my insert method from service

```
public Task<PersonResponse?> AddPersonAsync(PersonAddRequest addRequest)
        {
            Person newPerson = addRequest.ToPerson();
            _dbContext.Persons.Add(newPerson);
            _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Task.FromResult<PersonResponse?>(newPerson.ToResponse());
        }
```

But I Still Get 0 as PersonID on response
[image]

Comment: You forgot `await` - `await  _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: But if problem are on db doesn't solve the question. Check the field on db if use identity insert. if the "await" is omitted the exception is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `await` and insert into database performed later than response has been generated:

```cs
public async Task<PersonResponse?> AddPersonAsync(PersonAddRequest addRequest)
{
    Person newPerson = addRequest.ToPerson();
    _dbContext.Persons.Add(newPerson);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return newPerson.ToResponse();
}
```